# Multiple dependent native projects in visual studio

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012, native, project-management

Visual studio doesn't support native projects as it supports .NET projects. In the sense that when for example creating a static(`.lib`) library. Including of the static library, and the directory containing the headers, has to be done manually.

For one project this isn't some much of a problem. But if you're like me managing several projects. A lot of which are somewhat depenendend. It becomes a huge hassle to manage all of it.

I was wondering if there is any official 'microsoft approved' approach to this. And if not, what is the best way to deal with this situation. Supposing the following conditions occur:

- several static libraries(`.lib`) projects. Which are included in several solutions
- several dynamic libraries (`.dll`) projects. Which are included in several solutions
- multiple applications using the same libraries(both dynamic and static), in one solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My personal solution to the problem is as follows.

Every project generating a binary builds to:

```
$(SolutionDir)build\$(Configuration)\`
```

Every project generating a static library builds to:

```
$(SolutionDir)build\$(Configuration)\Libraries\
```

The intermediate directory for all projects is:

```
$(SolutionDir)build\$(ProjectName)\$(Configuration)\
```

And runs the following pre-build command:

```
Copy /Y "$(ProjectDir)*.h" + "$(ProjectDir)*.hpp"     "$(SolutionDir)build\$(Configuration)\Libraries\"
```

Advantages of this system include:

- All the project directories stay free of builds (useful when using source control). And all the binaries are in one place.
- Setting additional include directories is never required when using outputs from other projects in the same solution. A dynamic library doesn't have to be added at all. And all that is required to include a static library is adding it to the `Additional Dependencies` field under:

  `Configuration Properties->Linker->Input`

Drawbacks of this system include:

- Since all the header files are copied, the risk exists of accidentally  editing those. Which results in loss of work, when the copying occurs again.
- Since the settings are per project, they have to be set for ever project
- The libraries are built separately for every solution